# find in deep nested array (tree) recursivley

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, functional-programming, tree

I want to find a value in the following nested array **without using loops**:

```
let children = [
  {
    name: 'grand 1',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'parent 1.1',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'child 1.1.1',
            children: [
              // more...
            ]
          },
          // more...
        ],
      },
      // more...
    ],
  },
  // more...
];
```

This is what I'd do if I was only searching in the horizontal axis:

```
let childrenHorizontal = [
  { name: 'grand 1' },
  { name: 'grand 2' },
  { name: 'grand 3' },
  // more
];

function findHorizontal(name, childrenHorizontal) {
  let [head, ...tail] = childrenHorizontal;
  if (head.name === name)
    return head;
  else if (tail.length)
    return findHorizontal(name, tail);
}
```

But how do I search the nested array both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: Can you please give an example of the input and output?

Comment: @Asraf The input is literally the array at the start of the post. the output is a single element of that array.

Comment: for instance if we look for `name = child 1.1.1` it should return `{name: 'child 1.1.1',nchild: null }` right?

Comment: @Asraf Precisely. For the vertical version though.

Comment: Why don't you want loops ? Because you don't want fixed dimensions ? (because behind the scene, we have to use some kind of loop, but not necessarily in fixed dimensions)

Comment: @Lucasbk38 I have no idea what fixed dimensions are.

Comment: fixed dimensions means that you know "how deep" is every thing (like you know all your nodes have children and grand-children and that's it)

Comment: @Thore why do you want to avoid `loops` ?

Comment: @Lucasbk38 Yes as you already guessed the depth is not known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more generically, we can write a `deepFind` function that takes an arbitrary predicate and returns a function that tests a tree in a depth-first manner until it finds a matching node, returning `undefined` if no match is found. (This is JS, after all!)  Then we can write `findByName` as a function that that takes a target name and passes to `deepFind` a function that tests whether a given node's `name` matches that target.  It might look like this:

```js
const deepFind = (pred) => ([head, ...tail]) =>
  head == undefined
    ? undefined 
  : pred (head) 
    ? head 
  : deepFind (pred) (head .children) || deepFind (pred) (tail)

const findByName = (target) => deepFind (({name}) => name == target)

let children = [{name: 'grand 1', children: [{name: 'parent 1.1', children: [{name: 'child 1.1.1', children: []}]}, {name: 'parent 1.2', children: []}]}]


console .log ('parent 1.1:', findByName ("parent 1.1") (children))
console .log ('child 1.1.1:', findByName ("child 1.1.1") (children))
console .log ('parent 1.2:', findByName ("parent 1.2") (children))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

(Note that I added a `parent 1.2` node in the obvious location in the tree to demonstrate searching multiple children of one node.)

This finds the first node in a pre-order traversal of the tree that matches our predicate.  We use the short-circuiting feature of JavaScript's `||` operator to stop as soon as we've found a match.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. The trick is to concatenate the two axes:

```js
function find(name, children) {
  let [head, ...tail] = children;
  if (head.name === name)
    return head;
  return find(name, [...head.children, ...tail]);
}
```

But then I realized it is wasteful to concatenate the arrays when I can just use logical OR (using the [null-coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)):

```js
function find(name, children) {
  let [head, ...tail] = children
  if (head.name === name) return head
  return find(name, head.children) ?? find(name, tail) // no concat!
}
```

And I also learned that you must always check if the input array is empty, otherwise `head` could be undefined!

```js
function find(name, children) {
  if (children.length == 0) return; // exit early if children is empty
  let [head, ...tail] = children;
  if (head.name === name) return head;
  return find(name, head.children) ?? find(name, tail);
}
```

One possible way to restore the tail call is to use continuation-passing style:

```js
const identity = x => x

function find(name, children, k = identity) {
  if (children.length == 0) return;
  let [head, ...tail] = children;
  if (head.name === name) return k(head);
  return find(name, head.children, result => // tail find
    result ?? find(name, tail, k)            // tail find
  );
}
```

I also learned that destructuring assignment `let [head, ...tail]` creates new `tail` arrays - for *every* node along the way! `find` is a sort of *read* operation on the structure, so it would be wasteful to create single-use data along the way:

```js
function find(name, children, i = 0) {
  if (i >= children.length) return; // exit if i is out of bounds
  let head = children[i] // "head" is now a cursor over the array   
  if (head.name === name) return head;
  return find(name, head.children) ?? find(name, children, i + 1);
}
```

If I want the user to prevent accidentally passing initial `i` argument, I can wrap in an outer function. And I could add the CPS technique for tail call, if needed.

Comment: I made some updates to the post. I hope you find them useful :D

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I think the concatenating version is better because it's subject to tail call optimization. What do you think?

Comment: unfortunately there is no runtime that supports tail-call optimization in javascript. The array concatenation does unnecessary work in this case. And if tail call was necessary, the OR example can be converted to tail call using CPS.

Comment: Yes but I believe there's a babel plugin for it. Can you provide an example of the conversion?

Comment: Furthermore, concatenation wouldn't introduce any overhead in the case of a persistent data structure such as Immutable.js.

Comment: A plugin like that could work. Verify babel properly identifies all of your tail calls, and support for recursive generators. you maybe mistunderstand Immutable.js. If I have `x = [1,2]` and `y = [3,4]`, Immutable.js will concat them for `z = [1,2,3,4]` with the guarantee that `x` and `y` are not mutated. A new _is_ created.

Comment: Thanks for the updated examples. I was referring to structural sharing but maybe it doesn't work on arrays? Anyway your snippets look really interesting I'm gonna go on with them.

Comment: sure it's possible a sophisticated implementation of Array or List could do structural sharing. Traversing, look-up by index and `length` property means doing elaborate look-ups into the shared fragments. It's not impossible but tmk Immutable.js has a more straightforward solution.

Comment: I wrote a lot about [tail-recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20%5btail-recursion%5d) (more generally [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20%5brecursion%5d)) and [continuation-passing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20%5bcontinuation%5d). Ask me questions about these topics any time ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recursion :

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'grand 1',
    children: [{
        name: 'parent 1.1',
        children: [{
            name: 'child 1.1.1',
            children: []
          },
          // more...
        ],
      },
      // more...
    ],
  },
  // more...
];

const find = (name, children) => {
  for (const child of children) {
    // if the chidren's name corresopnds to the one provided, return it
    if (child.name === name) return child

    // here is the recursion
    const e = find(name, child.children)

    // if we found it on the child, we return the one found, else we keep going
    if (e) return e
  }

  // if none of the children or grand-children ... found, return null
  return null
}

console.log(find('parent 1.1', data))
```

Comment: That's exactly how I would write it using a for loop.

Comment: @Thore but it's the most efficient way because once you found it, you directly return it